# org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultSubMenu cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.UIComponent

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Im trying to upgrade from PrimeFaces 3.5 to PrimeFaces 4.0, the line of code that its fine on version 3.5 is this one:

```
private MenuModel modelPrincipal;
private Menubar menuBar;

menuBar.getChildren().addAll(modelPrincipal.getContents());
```

But when I upgrade to version 4.0 I have to change it as follows:

```
private org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuModel modelPrincipal;
private Menubar menuBar;
menuBar.getChildren().addAll((Collection<? extends UIComponent>) modelPrincipal.getElements());
```

and it throws the Exception of title, do you guys know a workaround for it? I couldn't find anything on the documentation of the migration https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

I also tried:

```
menuBar.getElements().addAll(modelPrincipal.getElements());
```

But gives me same Exception

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT (Minimal (this is as minimal as I could make the code to make the error appear) Reproducible Example):**

This is PrimeFaces 4.0:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;

import org.primefaces.component.menubar.Menubar;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuItem;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultSubMenu;

public class MenuExampleMB {
    private org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuModel modelPrincipal;
    private Menubar menuBar;
    private HashMap<String, SubMenuItemObject> menuUrlCodigos;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MenuExampleMB menuExampleMB = new MenuExampleMB();
        // MenuList
        List<MenuObject> menuList = new ArrayList<>();
        // SubMenuItemList
        List<SubMenuItemObject> subMenuList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Add 1 item to the SubMenuItemList
        subMenuList.add(new SubMenuItemObject("1", "SubMenu", "an url"));
        // MenuObject
        MenuObject menu1 = new MenuObject("Menu 1");
        // Set the SubMenu list for this MenuObject
        menu1.setlSubmenus(subMenuList);
        menuList.add(menu1);
        // Call method that brings the Exception
        menuExampleMB.loadMenu(menuList);
    }

    public void loadMenu(List<MenuObject> lMenus) {

        menuUrlCodigos = new HashMap<String, SubMenuItemObject>();
        modelPrincipal = new org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuModel();
        menuBar = new Menubar();
        // Go through the list of MenuObject and create each SubMenu and add them to
        // DefaultMenuModel
        for (MenuObject menu : lMenus) {
            DefaultSubMenu subMenu = new DefaultSubMenu();
            subMenu = agregarSubmenu(menu.getlSubmenus());
            subMenu.setLabel(menu.getTitulo());
            modelPrincipal.addElement(subMenu);
        }
        // This is the one that brings the exception.
        menuBar.getChildren().addAll((Collection<? extends UIComponent>) modelPrincipal.getElements());

    }

    private DefaultSubMenu agregarSubmenu(List<SubMenuItemObject> lSubMenuUsuario) {

        DefaultMenuItem menuItem = null;
        DefaultSubMenu subMenuPadre = new DefaultSubMenu();

        for (SubMenuItemObject subMenuItem : lSubMenuUsuario) {

            // Ask if this submenu has sons
            if (subMenuItem.getlSubmenus().size() > 0) {

                DefaultSubMenu subMenuHijo = new DefaultSubMenu();
                subMenuHijo.setLabel(subMenuItem.getTitulo());

                /*
                 * Invoke this method with recursivity to get all the sons of this menu
                 * 
                 */
                subMenuHijo.getElements().addAll(agregarSubmenu(subMenuItem.getlSubmenus()).getElements());

                // Add sons to the father submenu.
                subMenuPadre.getElements().add(subMenuHijo);

            } else {
                // This submenu doesn't have sons so its created as an unique son of the
                // father submenu.
                menuItem = agregarItem(subMenuItem);
                subMenuPadre.getElements().add(menuItem);
                subMenuPadre.setLabel(subMenuItem.getTitulo());
            }

        }

        return subMenuPadre;
    }

    private DefaultMenuItem agregarItem(SubMenuItemObject pSubMenuItem) {
        DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem();
        menuItem.setValue(pSubMenuItem.getTitulo());
        menuItem.setUrl(pSubMenuItem.getUrl());

        menuUrlCodigos.put(pSubMenuItem.getUrl(), pSubMenuItem);

        return menuItem;
    }

}

class MenuObject {
    private String titulo;
    private List<SubMenuItemObject> lSubmenus = new ArrayList<SubMenuItemObject>();

    public MenuObject(String pTitulo) {
        titulo = pTitulo;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public List<SubMenuItemObject> getlSubmenus() {
        return lSubmenus;
    }

    public void setlSubmenus(List<SubMenuItemObject> lSubmenus) {
        this.lSubmenus = lSubmenus;
    }
}

class SubMenuItemObject {
    private String codigo;
    private String titulo;
    private String url;
    private List<String[]> lJerarquia;
    private List<String> lTabs;
    private List<SubMenuItemObject> lSubmenus = new ArrayList<SubMenuItemObject>();

    public SubMenuItemObject(String pCodigo, String pTitulo, String pUrl) {
        codigo = pCodigo;
        titulo = pTitulo;
        url = pUrl;
        lJerarquia = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    }

    public SubMenuItemObject() {

    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public List<SubMenuItemObject> getlSubmenus() {
        return lSubmenus;
    }

    public void setlSubmenus(List<SubMenuItemObject> lSubmenus) {
        this.lSubmenus = lSubmenus;
    }

    public List<String[]> getlJerarquia() {
        return lJerarquia;
    }

    public void setlJerarquia(List<String[]> lJerarquia) {
        this.lJerarquia.clear();
        this.lJerarquia.addAll(lJerarquia);
    }

    public List<String> getlTabs() {
        return lTabs;
    }

    public void setlTabs(List<String> lTabs) {
        this.lTabs = lTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why to PF 4? Why not 7?

Comment: @Kukeltje I have to actually get it to 7 but I wanna do step by step mate because its big application migration to 7, or you suggest jumping to 7 directly? Im starting by the menu of the application too

Comment: I'd go directly to at least 6.1 (the latest with  older jquery)  There have been changes in datatables between 3,4,5 that afaik have been sort of reverted again, so it saves you suplicate work. You could try migrating to 7 as well but there  might be jquery changes needed if ypu have custom jquery code. But be sure to keep the migration documents of a;; intermediate versions at hand. But yes, the menu has undercone some changes too. If you can create a real [mcve] I'll see what I can do here. Good luck, good choice!

Comment: @Kukeltje okay thank you mate, I will try to make the minimal reproducible example cause im stuck at the moment with it hehe, I will let you know when its ready :)

Comment: @Kukeltje Hey bro, I added the code to make it appear, you can run it as java application if you paste it all in 1 file, please ask me if you need clarification with anything, I commented important stuff, variable names are in spanish, hope you can help me :)

Comment: Ok, will try tomorrow, but I was hoping you also have some small xhtml to show intention/usage but also a working 3.5 one to see the differences (you might have taken arong turn somewhere in migrating) . Cheers.

Comment: @Kukeltje okay bro, if tomorrow you don't manage to get anything with it I will try to make it more reproducible with xhtml, so far I have managed to upgrade everything else including PF() on dialogs and LazyDataModel changes, etc. Only having that issue with the menu, thank yo!

Comment: @Kukeltje by the way bro, you can confirm me if this RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("frmAnularDocumento"); is equivalent to this PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("frmAnularDocumento");  right, saw its another change to 7.0 https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2853

Comment: New questions belong in new questions,  but the migration guides contain this info, as does a highly upvoted q/a in stackoverf;ow

Comment: @Kukeltje Okay mate :) I found it, thank you, did you try the code I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classcast in

```
 menuBar.getChildren().addAll((Collection<? extends UIComponent>) modelPrincipal.getElements());
```

is sort of logical since the `org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuItem` elements in the model are not in any way a UIComponent (you can see this by following the source up to the base class/interface). Even if you'd not have explicitly casted this it would have failed with the same error but on another line in another class.

Doing the

```
menuBar.getElements().addAll(modelPrincipal.getElements());
```

Fails for the same reason. If you'd inspected the code in the `getElements()`  method in the `menuBar`, you'd have seen

```
public List getElements() {
    MenuModel model = getModel();
    if (model != null) {
        return model.getElements();
    }
    else {
        return getChildren();
    }
}
```

You could have even debugged it and seen that the model was null and then the `getChildren()` would be returned, effectively ending up in the same calls as in your first attempt. But...

You'd also see the `getModel()` in there, maybe being a hint in where to look for the solution. The menuBar has a `setModel(...)` to where you can set the model you programmatically created. So the solution for this is

```
menuBar.setModel(modelPrincipal);
```

IF you create the menuBar programmatically.

But most often it is added in the xhtml via

```
<p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}" />
```

Some additional hints:

- A search for "primefaces menu model 4.0 3.5" resulted in hits that would have given you help/hints (at least G00gle showed then to me)
- typing 'menumodel' in the PrimeFaces 7 documentation would have given a hint to the dynamic menu part in the generic menu component, having a full complete example. https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/menu
- Having an IDE with code completion in java code or xhtml and check the api's would have shown the `setModel` method or the `model` attribute.

But I agree, a little more explanation in the migration document would have helped, but at the time (when at least I migrated from 3.5 to 4) this was mentioned in the forums etc... so it was 'actual' at the time

Comment: Nice mate that looks like it will work, I will try it when I get back to my work station :) thank you

Comment: Hey mate it worked menu is loading! but now I have another problem hehe can you be around so you can help me with this migration exceptions? im having an exception saying: PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update() called but component can't be resolved!Expression will just be added to the renderIds.: org.primefaces.expression.ComponentNotFoundException: Cannot find component for expression "pnlEstadoSimple" referenced from "j_id1".  I am pretty sure cause im calling it wrong inside the update.

Comment: Like stated above, new questions in new questions (mind the [mcve]!!!). But try to see the 'generic' issue in your problems first. Many, many of them already have Q/A in stackoverflow. I was even sure this one had a Q/A too but could not find it (at least not close enough), but good search on 'primefaces menumodel  3.5 4' would have given enough hints to solve it ;-)

Comment: Okay lol, stay tunned cause I might ask again if I don't manage to solve it via searching hehe, thanks dude :)

Comment: bro, dude, mate... Liked the latter the best... Cheers... And mention in the new questions what you searched and why it did not help. See [ask]

Comment: hey brother can you check my last question about getting root-context of an application? I need to get that name, thanks